# Display summary in Blazor's Devexpress DataGrid

Tags: devexpress, blazor

Is there a way to display a summary footer in the current implementation of Devexpress' DataGrid for Blazor?

Comment: I've asked them for summaries for [groups](https://github.com/DevExpress/Blazor/issues/72) and they said they're working on it. I suggest you make an issue on their github regarding footer summaries